# How do I calculate the frequency in number of days of repeated orders using SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

| Date | Company | Item |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 02Jan | ABC | X |
| 15Jan | DEF | Y |
| 25Jan | GHI | Z |
| 02Feb | DEF | Y |
| 04Feb | ABC | X |
| 15Feb | DEF | Y |
| 18Feb | ABC | Z |

I have above table and I want to find the frequency in days when the company repeat the orders of a particular item. The frequency should be calculated from the last order. The result should look like below

| Date | Company | Item | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 02Jan | ABC | X | 0 |
| 15Jan | DEF | Y | 0 |
| 25Jan | GHI | Z | 0 |
| 02Feb | DEF | Y | 18 |
| 04Feb | ABC | X | 33 |
| 15Feb | DEF | Y | 13 |
| 18Feb | ABC | Z | 0 |

I tried creating row_number() over(PARTITION BY "Company" , "Item"  ) as "Frequency" however I did not get the desired result.

Can somebody please help me on this.

Comment: `DATEDIFF( date, LAG(date) )`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 02Jan

Assuming that's actually a DATE column (not varchar), instead of using ROW_NUMBER(), sort the results by date and use [LAG](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to obtain the last date an item was ordered. Then simply use DATE_DIFF() to calculate the difference.

```
 SELECT t.`Date`, t.Company, t.Item, COALESCE(DATEDIFF(t.`Date`, t.PrevDate),0) AS Frequency 
 FROM (
        SELECT *, LAG(`Date`, 1) OVER(PARTITION BY Company, Item ORDER BY `Date`) AS PrevDate
        FROM   YourTable
      ) t
```

**Results:**

| Date | Company | Item | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | ABC | X | 0 |
| 2022-02-05 | ABC | X | 34 |
| 2022-02-18 | ABC | Z | 0 |
| 2022-01-15 | DEF | Y | 0 |
| 2022-02-02 | DEF | Y | 18 |
| 2022-02-15 | DEF | Y | 13 |
| 2022-01-25 | GHI | Z | 0 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=9595bd1e7e42110293e7fe2757e42ae7)*